# Is there a way to read Qlikview data object using R and perform an statistical operation and return results to Qlikview?

Tags: r, api, open-source, qlikview

We are trying to build an application that can provide user the ability to chose an statistical operation using Qlikview, then load the data into R and perform the operation selected by user, and finally display the results using Qlikview. I'm using statconn DCON as an interface between R and Qlikview.

I tried with an example available on [web](http://community.qlikview.com/docs/DOC-3981#start=25) (thanks a lot to Brian), but there data is transferred using CSV files. To elaborate - first the user selects filters in Qlikview dashboard and the data is exported as CSV file, then R reads the CSV and performs the operation and exports the result again in CSV format. And finally, Qlikview reads the CSV file and displays on the dashboard.

I was hoping that if the CSV operation can be avoided it can help in working with huge files having millions of rows. And for that, we need to have some method which can help read/load the Qlikview data object in R and after R operation changes format back to Qlikview data object. Therefore, looking for inputs from folks having some experience or idea about the same. I'll be very grateful for the help.

Best regards,
Tanmay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use winform/OCX and access the QV document and suck data right out of the document and then pump data back into the document using dynamic SQL.
[Look at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991384/alternatives-to-macros-for-accessing-data-objects/21089437#21089437)

But be warned that this is not without its own pitfalls and problems.